# The limit of difference between $E\ln (1+X)$ and $\ln(E(1+X))$

Tags: real-analysis, probability, random-variables

Define a random variable $X=v^2$ where $v$ is Gaussian variable with mean $m$ and variance $\sigma^2$. I am interested in whether
$$\lim_{m \rightarrow \infty} (E\ln(1+X) - \ln(E(1+X))) \rightarrow0 $$

where the variance $\sigma^2$ still remains a constant.

The following is the result of difference between $E\ln(1+X)$ and $\ln(E(1+X))$ as $m$ increases exponentially.

[image]

We can see the difference approaches to 0 as the increase of $m$. So I guess $\ln(E(1+X))$ is the upper bound of $E(\ln (1+X))$. Is it true and how to prove or disprove it?

Thank you!

Comment: In what sense does your limit make sense? On the left of your limit hypothesis it looks like you've got a sequence of expectations related to a sequence of probability measures and random variables. On far right you seem to have picked a preferred random variable and probability measure, but which one is unclear because it is in terms of $m$ which is not fixed (i.e. $m\to\infty$ on the l.h.s.).

Comment: @ki3i I have modified my question. Is it more clear for you?

Comment: could you please say what $m$ is?

Comment: @Mehdi  $m$ is the mean of $v$.

Comment: Hint: Find some sufficient condition on the random variable $Z$ to ensure that $E(\log Z_m)\to0$ when $m\to\infty$, where $$Z_m=(1+m^{-1}Z)^2+m^{-2}.$$

Comment: @Did well..your hint is so brief, and I am confused about it. Can you provide any more information?

Comment: @NalRa Lebesgue dominated convergence theorem (what else?).

Comment: @Did Well, I admit that I don't hear about it before. I have posted a answer to this question. Can you help check whether this proof is strict enough. Actually, I am still uncertain about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Henry's example shows why you're seeing $\ln(E(1+X))$ as an upper bound.

**Lets try to prove that this difference converges to 0**

Let $Y_m:= \ln(1+X_m)$

Note that $E[1+X_m]=m^2+\sigma^2+1$ and $E[Y_m]\geq 0$ by its definition.

By Markov's Inequality:

$$P(Y_m>a)\leq \frac{E[Y_m]}{a}\implies E[Y_m]\geq aP(Y_m>a)$$

However, by Jensen's Inequality:

$$\ln(1+m^2+\sigma^2)\geq E[Y_m]$$

Combining these gives:

$$aP(Y_m>a)\leq E[Y_m]\leq\ln(1+m^2+\sigma^2)$$

Now:

$$P(Y_m>a)=P(X_m<e^a-1)=P(v_m>\sqrt{e^a-1})+P(v_m<-\sqrt{e^a-1})$$

Standardizing $v_m$ we get:

$$P(Y_m>a)=1-\Phi\left(\frac{\sqrt{e^a-1}-m}{\sigma}\right)+\Phi\left(\frac{-\sqrt{e^a-1}-m}{\sigma}\right)$$

Thus:

$$a\left[1-\Phi\left(\frac{\sqrt{e^a-1}-m}{\sigma}\right)+\Phi\left(\frac{-\sqrt{e^a-1}-m}{\sigma}\right)\right]\leq E[Y_m]\leq \ln(1+m^2+\sigma^2),\;\forall a>0$$

Lets set $a=k\ln(1+m^2+\sigma^2),k\in(0,1)$:

$$k\ln(1+m^2+\sigma^2)\left[1-\Phi\left(\frac{(m^2+\sigma^2)^{0.5k}-m}{\sigma}\right)+\Phi\left(\frac{-(m^2+\sigma^2)^{0.5k}-m}{\sigma}\right)\right]\leq E[Y_m]\leq \ln(1+m^2+\sigma^2)$$

Taking the limit of the LHS:

$$\lim_{m\to \infty} k\ln(1+m^2+\sigma^2)\left[1-\Phi\left(\frac{(m^2+\sigma^2)^{0.5k}-m}{\sigma}\right)+\Phi\left(\frac{-(m^2+\sigma^2)^{0.5k}-m}{\sigma}\right)\right] = k\ln(1+m^2+\sigma^2)$$

Since $\forall k \in (0,1): (m^2+\sigma^2)^{0.5k}-m=O(m)$; therefore,

$$ k\ln(1+m^2+\sigma^2)\leq E[Y_m]\leq \ln(1+m^2+\sigma^2)$$

Maximizing the lower bound by letting $k\to 1$ gives:

$$ \ln(1+m^2+\sigma^2)\leq E[Y_m]\leq \ln(1+m^2+\sigma^2) \implies \lim_{m\to \infty} E[Y_m]=\ln(1+m^2+\sigma^2)$$

$\square$

Comment: There is a mistake in your answer. After standardizing $v_m$, then it should follow: $$P(Y_m>a)=1-\Phi\left(\frac{\sqrt{e^a-1}-m}{\sigma}\right)+\Phi\left(-\frac{ \sqrt{e^a-1} \color{red}{+} m}{\sigma}\right)$$

Comment: But the reasoning process still holds by setting $a=k \ln (1+m^2+\sigma^2)$ instead of $\ln (1+m^2+\sigma^2)$, where k approaches to 1 but cannot be equal to $1$.

Comment: @NalRa thanks for pointing that out. I fixed the signs. Yes, the logic will still work with your approach too. Either way, you get the limit by the squeeze theorem.

Comment: Actually, I have another concern about the last step of your reasoning process, If $\lim_{m\rightarrow \infty} \frac{f(m)}{\ln(1+m^2)}=1$, can we say that $\lim f(m) = \lim (\ln (1+m^2))$?

Comment: @NalRa See here: http://dl.uncw.edu/digilib/mathematics/calculus/limits/freeze/LimitLaws.html#MapleAutoBookmark13. We could also apply the difference rule to the log of the ratio.

Comment: Here is an example, $\lim_{N \rightarrow \infty} \frac{N-1}{N}=1$, but $\lim N-1 \neq \lim N$

Comment: @NalRa you are correct. I need to demonstrate that the numerator cannot differ by some constant value. Will need to think about this some more...seems like the proof is almost there...

Comment: Well...I have posted my answer, which is mostly based on your idea, would you please to check if this proof is strict?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/20864/discussion-between-nalra-and-eupraxis1981).

Answer (score 2):

Let $Y=1+X$, By Jensen's inequality, we can have 
$$E(Y)<\ln(E(1+X))=\ln(1+m^2+\sigma^2)$$
Since $Y=\ln (1+v^2)>0$, apply Markov inequality, for any $a>0$, 
$$P(Y>a)\leq \frac{EY}{a}$$
$$EY\geq aP(Y>a)$$
So we have
$$aP(Y>a)\leq EY \leq \ln(1+m^2+\sigma^2)$$ 
Set $a=k \ln(1+m^2+\sigma^2)$, where $0<k<1$.
$$P(Y>a)=1-\Phi\left(\frac{(m^2+\sigma^2)^{0.5k}-m}{\sigma}\right)+\Phi\left(\frac{-(m^2+\sigma^2)^{0.5k}-m}{\sigma}\right)$$
So $$aP(Y>a)=k\ln(1+m^2+\sigma^2)(1-\Phi\left(\frac{(m^2+\sigma^2)^{0.5k}-m}{\sigma}\right)+\Phi\left(\frac{-(m^2+\sigma^2)^{0.5k}-m}{\sigma}\right))$$

Next we show that 
$$D=\lim_{m \rightarrow \infty} k\ln(1+m^2+\sigma^2)\left[\Phi\left(\frac{(m^2+\sigma^2)^{0.5k}-m}{\sigma}\right)-\Phi\left(\frac{-(m^2+\sigma^2)^{0.5k}-m}{\sigma}\right)\right]=0$$

Firstly because $\Phi\left(\frac{(m^2+\sigma^2)^{0.5k}-m}{\sigma}\right) \geq \Phi\left(\frac{-(m^2+\sigma^2)^{0.5k}-m}{\sigma}\right)$
So $D \geq 0$.

And $D \leq \lim_{m \rightarrow \infty} \ln(1+m^2+\sigma^2)\Phi\left(\frac{(m^2+\sigma^2)^{0.5k}-m}{\sigma}\right)$

Let $M=(m^2+\sigma^2)^{0.5k}-m$, note that because $k<1$, so the order of $M$ is the same as $m$, and $M \rightarrow -\infty$ as $m \rightarrow \infty$

$$
\begin{aligned}
D &\leq \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \lim_{m \rightarrow \infty} \ln(1+m^2+\sigma^2)  \int_{-\infty}^{M} e^\frac{-x^2}{2} \, dx \\
&\leq \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \lim_{m \rightarrow \infty} \ln(1+m^2+\sigma^2)  \int_{-M}^{\infty} e^{-x} \, dx \\
&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \lim_{m \rightarrow \infty} \ln(1+m^2+\sigma^2)e^M=0
\end{aligned}
$$

Then we have 
$$\lim_{m \rightarrow \infty} aP(Y>a)=k\ln(1+m^2+\sigma^2)$$
Because the choice of $k$ is arbitrary except $0<k<1$, let's choose $k$ approach to 1. Then 
$$\lim_{k \rightarrow 1} \lim_{m \rightarrow \infty} aP(Y>a)=\ln(1+m^2+\sigma^2)$$

$$\ln (1+m^2+\sigma^2)\leq \lim_{m \rightarrow \infty} E(Y) \leq \ln (1+m^2+\sigma^2)$$

So $$\lim_{m \rightarrow \infty} E(Y) = \ln(1+m^2+\sigma^2)$$

Comment: In your defintion of $D$, did you mean to have a $k$ in from of the logarithm?

Comment: @Eupraxis1981 yes, I want to show $D=0$.

Comment: I'm no @Did, but for what it's worth, your proof appears sound. I incorporated your insight about limiting the order of $a$ into my response as well.

Comment: @Eupraxis1981 Actually, what I am worry about is the limit of $k$. That is when $k$ approaches to 1, whether this will put some influence on our $\lim$ on m? Can we just separate $m$ and $k$ as we assume?

Comment: The limit in $m$ can be thought of as a function of k, $f(k)$. As with all limits, $\lim_{k\to 1} f(k)$ does not necessarily have to equal $f(1)$, as $f(k)$ can have a point of discontinuity at that point. This appears to be the case.

Comment: @Eupraxis1981 I understand what you mean and I come to believe that this proof is sound. Your answer is accepted and thank you for your help :)

Comment: It was a team effort :) This was instructive for me as well!

Answer (score 1):

This is essentially an example of [Jensen's inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen's_inequality) as the logarithm is a concave function $f$ with the property $$f(E[X]) \ge E[f(X)]$$ resulting from the concavity of $f$.

The direction of the inequality would reverse for a convex function.

Comment: Quote: "I am interested in whether [some limit = 0]".